# How to enable scheduled refresh using a custom OAuth2 connector for Google Spreadsheets in PowerBI Service?

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, google-oauth, connector

I'm building a custom connector for Google Spreadsheets in PowerBI. My connector works great in PowerBI Desktop, but is running into problems when being used in PowerBI Service. Has anybody gotten this to work correctly?

I can schedule the refresh of the report that is using the connector in PowerBI Service, which I think means that:

- My gateway connection is working
- My custom connector is correctly recognized by the gateway
- The OAuth2 credentials dialog is working, meaning that the StartLogin and FinishLogin functions functioning properly

Howerver, PowerBI Service returns the following error when actually refreshing at the scheduled refresh time or when refreshing the report manually:

```
{"error":
 {"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_OAuthTokenRefreshFailedError","pbi.error":
  {"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_OAuthTokenRefreshFailedError","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
```

Which seems to point to an error in the Refresh or TokenRefresh funcions that I'm using. I don't think this is a limitation of PowerBI Service as it seems that others have managed to get this to work.

Pasting my full code below for reference, because I'm unsure where exactly the error originates. Credits to the following sources for inspiration on the code:

- https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/09/24/custom-connector-import-google-sheets-oauth2-powerbi/
- https://www.skolenipowerbi.cz/l/google-drive-connector-kompletni-pruvodce/

My current code:

```
// This file contains your Data Connector logic
section PQGoogleSpreadsheet;

// Google OAuth2 values
client_id = Text.FromBinary(Extension.Contents("client_id.txt"));
client_secret = Text.FromBinary(Extension.Contents("client_secret.txt"));
redirect_uri = "https://preview.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html";
token_uri = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

// Login window dimensions
windowWidth = 1200;
windowHeight = 1000;

// Data Source Kind description
[DataSource.Kind="PQGoogleSpreadsheet", Publish="PQGoogleSpreadsheet.UI"]

shared PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Contents = Value.ReplaceType(PQGoogleSpreadsheetCore.Contents, 
                                      type function (#"Google Spreadsheet url" as Uri.Type) as any);

shared PQGoogleSpreadsheetCore.Contents = (url as text) =>
    let
        finalUrl = Text.BeforeDelimiter(url, "/", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}) & "/export?format=xlsx",
        content = Web.Contents(finalUrl),
        excel = Excel.Workbook(content, null, true)
    in
        excel;

// Contents description
PQGoogleSpreadsheet = [
    TestConnection = (dataSourcePath) => {"PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Contents", dataSourcePath}, 
    Authentication = [
        OAuth = [
            StartLogin = StartLogin,
            FinishLogin = FinishLogin,
            Logout = Logout,
            Refresh = Refresh,
            Label = "Google Spreadsheet Auth"
        ]
    ],
    Label = "Google Spreadsheet Connector"
];

// Helper functions for OAuth2: StartLogin, FinishLogin, Refresh, Logout
StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) => 
    let
        AuthorizeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
            response_type = "code",
            client_id = client_id,
            redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
            access_type = "offline",
            include_granted_scopes = "true",
            state = state,
            scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
            ])
    in
        [
            LoginUri = AuthorizeUrl,
            CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
            WindowHeight = windowHeight,
            WindowWidth = windowWidth,
            Context = null
        ];

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>
   let
       // Parse the full callbackUri, and extract the Query string
       Parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query],
       // if the query string contains an "error" field, raise an error
       // otherwise call TokenMethod to exchange our code for an access_token
       Result = if (Record.HasFields(Parts, {"error", "error_description"})) then
                   error Error.Record(Parts[error], Parts[error_description], Parts)
               else if (Record.HasFields(Parts, {"error"})) then 
                   if (Parts[error] = "access_denied") then
                       error Error.Record("Access Denied", "This account does not have access to " & context & ".")
                   else 
                       error Error.Record(Parts[error], "Failed to login to " & context & ".")
               else if (Record.HasFields(Parts, {"code"})) then
                   TokenMethod("authorization_code", "code", Parts[code])
               else
                   error Error.Record(Text.Combine(Table.ToList(Record.ToTable(Parts), 
                                                   Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", "))))
   in
       Result;

TokenMethod = (grantType, tokenField, code) => 
   let
       QueryString = [
           grant_type = grantType,
           redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
           access_type = "offline",
           client_id = client_id,
           client_secret = client_secret
           ],
       QueryWithCode = Record.AddField(QueryString, tokenField, code),
       TokenResponse = Web.Contents("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", [
           Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(QueryWithCode)),
           Headers = [
               #"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               #"Accept" = "application/json"
               ],
           ManualStatusHandling = {400} 
           ]),
       Body = Json.Document(TokenResponse),
       Result = if (Record.HasFields(Body, {"error", "error_description"})) then 
                   error Error.Record(Body[error], Body[error_description], Body)
               else if (Record.HasFields(Body, {"error"})) then 
                   error Error.Record(Body[error], "Failed to login.", Body)
               else
                   Body
   in
       Result;

Refresh = (resourceUrl, refresh_token) => TokenMethod("refresh_token", "refresh_token", refresh_token); 

Logout = (access_token) => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" & access_token;

// Data Source UI publishing description
PQGoogleSpreadsheet.UI = [
    Beta = true,
    Category = "Other",
    ButtonText = { "Google Spreadsheet Connector", "Google Spreadsheet Connector Help" },
    SourceImage = PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Icons,
    SourceTypeImage = PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Icons
];

PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Icons = [
    Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet16.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet20.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet24.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet32.png") },
    Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet32.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet40.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet48.png"), 
               Extension.Contents("PQGoogleSpreadsheet64.png") }
];
```

I've tried using different authorization urls and redirect urls (for example, https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html in stead of https://preview.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html). I've also tried passing dataSourcePath to the refresh function and passing it to TokenMethod as well, but all of these to no avail. I've tried modified the context in the startlogin function to be non-null, but that did not help either.

Can anybody point out to me why my OAuth2 refresh is not working for PowerBI Service, and what I can do to make it work? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add TestConnection Part here:
PQGoogleSpreadsheet = [
TestConnection = (dataSourcePath) => {"PQGoogleSpreadsheet.Contents", dataSourcePath},
Authentication = [

More info here:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Why-does-my-Custom-Connector-not-refresh/m-p/1054178